# Is there a timeline for Siri location features to be brought to Canada?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, siri

Currently, the location features for Siri don't work in Canada. Is there a timeline for that being rolled out, or is there any way to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Apple announced that Siri location services will come to Canada and several other countries when iOS 6 is released in the fall.

You can see the full list of supported languages and locations [here](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/siri/).